# Перезаписать массив Files удалив пустое место

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вот HTML

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="file" id="myfiles" multiple type="file"  />
<button type="submit" class="ancSubmit">send</button>
</form>
```

Вот JS

```
const fileInput = document.querySelector('#myfiles');
const files = [];
const pushFiles = function(){
files.push(...fileInput.files);
}
document.querySelector('#myfiles').onchange = pushFiles;
```

Код console.log(files) выдает

```
(2) [File, File]
```

После этого кода

```
    var index = 1;
    var i = 0;
    for (const file of files) {
      if (i == index) {
        delete files[i];
      }
      i++;
    }
console.log(files)
```

Консоль выдала следующее

```
(2) [File, пусто]
```

То есть осталось два элемента но один пустой. Массив нужно перезаписать, убрав пустое место.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
var index = 2; 
for (const file of files) {
  if (i == index) {
    delete files[i];
  }
  i++;
}
const result = files.filter((x) => x !== 2);
files.splice(0);
for (const resFile of result) {
  files.push(resFile);
}
console.log(files);
```

Answer (score 1):

delete не удаляет полностью элемент из массива, лишь очищает значение. Для удаления - массив нужно пересоздать без удаленного элемента. И здесь можно отфильтровать или обрезать и склеить.

```js
let files = [1,2,3,4];
let index = 2;
/* files = [...files.slice(0,index), ...files.slice(index + 1, )] */
files = [...files.filter((el,i) => index !== i)]
console.log(files)
```